# How to adjust imageview?

Tags: android, android-layout

I have retrived the images from sdcard of emulator and added to my grid view.but they are not getting displayed in proper manner.![enter image description here][1]

Could you please help me..
Also i posted my ImageAdapter.java
please suggest any changes in it..
Thanks

```
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter 
{
    ArrayList<Images> array=new ArrayList<Images>();

    Context mContext; 
    private LayoutInflater mInflater; 



    public ImageAdapter(Context c,ArrayList<Images> arr) 
    {
        mContext = c;  
        array=arr;
        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
        Log.e("","adapter con");
    }


    public int getCount()
    {
            Log.e("Count",""+array.size());
        return array.size();
    }

    public Object getItem(int index)
    {
         //return 0;
        return array.get(index);
    }

    public long getItemId(int index) 
    {

        return index;
    }
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        //    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams =new //RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(30, 30);

        ImageView imageView = new ImageView(mContext);

        Images i=array.get(position);
        imageView.setImageBitmap(i.getBitmap());

        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
        imageView.animate();
       //       imageView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);



        return imageView;
    }
}
```

Comment: i am new user and dnt have too much reputations .so don't allow me to attach image

Comment: then any other way tell what is the problem?

Comment: The grid view of images is displyed like hows grid view of default gallery is getting displayed

Comment: @PranandPatil: upload your image at http://imgur.com and paste the link here..

Comment: My applications image grid view looks like http://imgur.com/BzT5F and defaut gallery applications image grid view looks like http://imgur.com/wFpWn (which i want)

Comment: @Adil Soomro:I have updated image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. This should work,

```
        imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
        imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(85, 85));
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
```

Answer (score 0):

you have define Layout param 
LayoutParam layoutparam = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_Parent,LayoutParams.FILL_Parent);
 imageView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);

Comment: It gives following error on fo that                                  : java.lang.ClassCastException: android.view.ViewGroup$LayoutParams cannot be cast to android.widget.AbsListView$LayoutParams

Comment: try as below  LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutparams= new LinearLayout.layoutParams(LayoutParama.FILL_PARENT,LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);